# Bitlocker disabled but asking for encrypting

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, encryption, bitlocker

Every time I insert a USB drive in my work PC, I get **Before you can save files on this drive, you need to encrypt it using Bitlocker.**
Various online resources point about turning off Bitlocker which is already done for the hard drive and the external devices.

It boots normally and no password or keys are asked. So how to solve this problem?

EDIT:Since I am seeing votes to close asking for more clarifications, it is a Windows 10 PC with Visual Studio installed. It is used for development, users login to a domain through it, but I used the `.\administrator` to find the information posted above.

Comment: Odd. Sounds almost like fake message from malware to me. Or maybe, some kind of corporate policy?

Comment: It might be a corporate policy. Since people log in to a domain, but I used a local administrator account.

Comment: Yes; I would agree; It sounds like a group policy is enforcing the rule. You’ll have to provide more details if you want help

Comment: What kind of details?

Comment: Is this a computer owned or managed by a company?

Comment: @TomYan this is the exact wording of the normal prompt based on group policy requirements.

Comment: Yes, it is managed and owned by a company, so where this policy is found and how to disable it?

Comment: If the computer is a domain member and the group policy is applied through that domain then you can not change it, as it is the purpose of a group policy to apply restrictions even a local admin can not change. The only way would be to leave the domain and then change the local group policy.